# MySQLdb Executemany error

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm having issues with executemany returning the following error

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IBM'',''1998-01-02 09:30:00'',''104.5'',''104.5'',''104.5'',''104.5'',''67000'')' at line 2")
```

Whats interesting is I'm using the EXACT same syntax successfully with just plain execute command. To demonstrate, this code will successfully add a record using execute, however using the SAME syntax with execute many is returning the above error. Any insight?

```
import MySQLdb
from MySQLdb import *
import datetime



db1 = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",user="root",passwd="password")
c = db1.cursor()
c.execute("use securities_master")


testdata = [('IBM', datetime.datetime(1998, 1, 2, 9, 30), '104.5', '104.5', '104.5', '104.5', '67000'),
    ('IBM', datetime.datetime(1998, 1, 2, 9, 31), '104.375', '104.5', '104.375', '104.375', '10800'),
    ('IBM', datetime.datetime(1998, 1, 2, 9, 32), '104.4375', '104.5', '104.375', '104.5', '13300'),
    ('IBM', datetime.datetime(1998, 1, 2, 9, 33), '104.4375', '104.5', '104.375', '104.375', '16800'),
    ('IBM', datetime.datetime(1998, 1, 2, 9, 34), '104.375', '104.5', '104.375', '104.375', '4801'),
    ('IBM', datetime.datetime(1998, 1, 2, 9, 35), '104.4375', '104.5', '104.375', '104.375', '23300'),
    ('IBM', datetime.datetime(1998, 1, 2, 9, 36), '104.4375', '104.4375', '104.375', '104.4375', '2600'),
    ('IBM', datetime.datetime(1998, 1, 2, 9, 37), '104.375', '104.375', '104.375', '104.375', '2800'),
    ('IBM', datetime.datetime(1998, 1, 2, 9, 38), '104.375', '104.4375', '104.375', '104.4375', '11101')]

sql = """INSERT IGNORE INTO stocks_datamine (symbol_id,price_date,open_price,high_price,low_price,close_price,volume) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')"""

for record in testdata[:1]:#test insert on one record
    sql_statement = sql%record
    c.execute(sql_statement)
    db1.commit()
    print 'success!'

#same sql statement just for multiple records - returns error :(


c.executemany(sql, testdata)
db1.commit()
```

Comment: Don't put quotes around `%s` in the SQL. The library adds quotes when it performs its substitution, so you're ending up with two qutoes.

Comment: ok, I removed the quotes around %s.. Same error,(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '09:30:00,104.5,104.5,104.5,104.5,67000)' at line 1")

Comment: Can you update question with the latest query without quotes.

Comment: Weird. Now it looks like it's not adding any quotes. I don't know why it would only add quotes when the query already has quotes, and not add them when it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `sql` query, you added quotes to `%s` (remove them):

```
sql = """INSERT ... VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
```

Comment: so quoted formatting characters works on a single execute but not executemany. thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you do in the for loop is wrong. 
You are formatting query as string with `sql_statement = sql%record`, this is not the correct way.
You are constructing a query, this is what you are using MySQLdb for.

What you need to do is the following:

```
# remove quotes from the query
sql = """INSERT IGNORE INTO stocks_datamine (symbol_id,price_date,open_price,high_price,low_price,close_price,volume) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""

for record in testdata:
    # let MySQLdb to handle parameters.
    c.execute(sql_statement, record)
    db1.commit()
```